# AVAudioPlayer error "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1954115647.)" swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I'm getting an error when trying to play a file I have stored in data from my AvAudioPlayer. The code was working fine in Swift 3 but I think Swift 4 - 4.2 had something to do with it. The data is not nil either. Not sure what It could be.

```
try AVAudioPlayer(data: song.songFile as Data) // data is not nil
```

I just want the AvAudioPlayer to play this, But I get the error:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1954115647.)

I get this from

```
catch let error as NSError {
    print("Unresolved error \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Comment: Change the `catch` to: `catch { print("Error: \(error)") }`. Then post the complete error in your question.

Comment: What is `song.songFile` and why do you need to cast it to `Data`?

Comment: @rmaddy  songFile is of type data. Also changed the code to what you said and got this "Unresolved error Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=1954115647 "(null)"
"

Comment: do you have any luck with `AVAudioPlayer(data: song.songFile as Data, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.<ENTER_FILE_FORMAT_HERE>.rawValue)` for supported [`AVFileType`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avfiletype)?